# I want to inform the user that only one seat can be selected in my windows form booking system

Tags: c#, winforms

Im creating a booking system and have a seat reservation UI where the user can choose a seat. if its available, it will turn green and if they click it again it turns grey etc.

I want a pop up box to appear if the user attempts to select more than one seat. Each picture box is part of the same click event.

This is what i have so far:

```
    Bitmap availableSeat = Properties.Resources.availableSeat;
    Bitmap seatTaken = Properties.Resources.SeatTaken;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {                  
       var pb = (PictureBox) sender;

        if (pb.Image == availableSeat)
        {
            n+=1;
            pb.Image = seatTaken;               
        }
        else 
        {
            pb.Image = availableSeat;
            n-=1;
        }
        if (n > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Only one seat can be selected.");               
        }

        selectedSeatNo = pb.Tag.ToString();
    }
```

I dont understand why this isnt working. if i do "if(n == 1)" and put the value of n equal to 1, once a seat has changed to "seatTaken" the message box appears. So why isnt this?

Comment: You're declaring `int n = 0` in the Click handler. Each time a PictureBox is clicked, `n` restarts from `0`. Move it outside, declare it as a Field instead of a Local Variable.

Comment: `if (pb.Image == availableSeat)` is not a good idea. You should rather use a data structure independent of the UI. The day you will want to reuse the logic, it will be impossible. As for the use of `n` to keep track of selected seats, I would rather avoid a class variable and count the selected seats. More expensive but more reliable too.

Comment: @Jimi I've made the changes above, moved n outside and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Images don't have a way to test for equality.

Comment: What are `availableSeat` and `seatTaken`? When and how are you declaring these two? How are you setting the Image property of your PictureBoxes? Are you creating a new Image each time, possibly taken from the Resources? Wouldn't it be better to have a class that handles the relation between a Seat and its State (free/occupied) and a property that tracks the number of seats that a user has picked? In any case, you should check whether `n` is already equal to `1` before you allow to book a seat, otherwise you just show a MessageBox, but the seat has already been marked as taken.

Comment: The same applies when a seat is unbooked. I don't know what this app is supposed to show to the user, but, as of now, you could unbook any seat in the interface without any *consequence*.

Comment: @LarsTech  New Image objects are harder to compare for equality (though just `SequenceEquals()` would do), but references of Images can be compared. If those `availableSeat` and `seatTaken` are Bitmaps stored as, e.g., Fields and you assign one of these Fields to the Image property, you're comparing references and the comparison will give positive or negative results accordingly. Won't happen in case the Images are assigned directly from a Resource object, form know reasons.

Comment: @Jimi availableSeat and seatTaken are both Bitmaps which I've set through properties.Resources. The app will store the seat Number inside of a table, then what i would like to do once, i have this current issue sorted is iterate through each pictureBox on the userControl to check which seats have been taken. If they are taken then i will want to change all seats to red(another image). I'll take your advice and create a separate class that manages each of the seats, i'm not sure how to do it, but ill give it a go and see what I come up with